# After combine two files by awk space become tab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Hi I have one Simple AWK for combining two files.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2 OFS $10 OFS $11 OFS $13; next }
{ $1 = $1 }
FNR !=  1 { print $0, a[$1] }
' $2 $1 > $3
```

One of Column in $1 File contain Character 'Not Perfect'

After Combine two files this character become Tab delimited.
Like 'Not\tPerfect'

Anyone has good idea why it's happening?

Comment: $1 does not contain `Not Perfect`.  $1 is `Not` and $2 is `Perfect`, and setting $1 = $1 causes $0 to be rewritten using OFS as the field separator, and you have made OFS be a tab.

Comment: Give some example data on input and what output you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the output separator character `OFS` to `'\t'` so any place where you print two things separated by a comma, such as:

```
print $0, a[$1]
```

You'll get:

```
<contents of $0 i.e. the whole input line>\t<the '$1'th value of 'a'>
```

So either set `OFS` to a space, or whatever you want using:

```
OFS=' '
```

or just use `printf` instead to avoid implicit use of `OFS` like:

```
printf("%s %s\n", $0, a[$1])
```